# Getting ranked stats from PUBG api

Tags: node.js

I am studying NodeJs and testing random examples.
I have successfully installed pubg.js module to node js and got it working.

Getting season stats works fine with /players/$playerId/seasons/$seasonId.

Getting ranked stats returns Bad Request /players/$playerId/seasons/$seasonId/ranked
Here is my method getting ranked stats. Removing /ranked will successfully return season stats.

```
getRanked(player, season, shard) {
    return this._baseRequest({
        endpoint: `players/${
            player instanceof Player ? player.id : player
        }/seasons/${
            season instanceof Season ? season.id : season
        }/ranked`,
        shard:
            player instanceof Player ?
                player.attributes.shardId :
                shard || this.defaultShard,
    })
        .then(ps => {
            if (player instanceof Player) ps.data.relationships.player = new Player(_.omit(player, ['relationships']));

            return new PlayerSeason(ps.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            throw e.message;
        });
}
```

Pubg js module can be found: [here](https://pubg.js.org/)
And api docs [here](https://documentation.pubg.com/en/getting-started.html#getting-player-ranked-stats)

Comment: Where are these two?
-H "Authorization: Bearer $api-key" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json"

Comment: Those are build in pubg.js module. Client._baseRequest(). As you I stated the request works fine without /ranked in the end so headers should be fine.

Comment: Some value from player or seson must be undefined or not according to docs

Comment: "Some value from player or seson must be undefined or not" I do not get this please. point out where in the docs this is stated. @SyedMohibUddin

Comment: By docs I meant pubg documentation or from front end some values passing to params may be undefined or null check once by placing console.log() before hitting to api